# 'Doc' is undefined in IE11

Tags: javascript

I have an issue with my sample website which gave me an error: Doc is undefined showing in dev tools which happens at this line: Doc.Show.init();

Any suggestion why it did not work in IE11 but worked in chrome and firefox

Thanks in advance.

```js
'use strict'

var Doc = Doc || {};

Doc.Show = function() {

    let init = function init() {
        console.log("nothing to show");
    };

    return {
        init: init
    };
}();
```

```css
h1 {
    color: red;
    text-align: center;
}

blockquote::before {
    content: open-quote;
}

blockquote::after {
    content: close-quote;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style.css">

    <script src="/script/doc.js"></script>
    <script>
        Doc.Show.init();
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>This is Header one</h1>
    <blockquote>This is blockquote</blockquote>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I dont see your script referenced from your HTML.

Comment: You dont import that script anywhere

Comment: I edited the question to include them

Comment: Pretty sure `'use strict'` prevents your `var Doc` from polluting the global scope. You should instead to `window.Doc = window.Doc || {};`

Comment: @connexo Actually no.  Its tricky, but `Show` is actually an IIFE.  It's a function that is declared and immediately called, assigning an object to `Show`.

Comment: @dfsq and quite easy to overlook that trailing `()`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is this line:

```
var Doc = Doc || {};
```

You're trying to use the global variable `Doc` in the initialization of `Doc`. This gets an error if the global variable doesn't already exist, because strict mode won't automatically create global variables.

Strict mode also doesn't allow creating global variables by declaring them at top level. You have to create them as `window` properties.

```
window.Doc = window.Doc || {};

window.Doc.Show = function() {

    let init = function init() {
        console.log("nothing to show");
    };

    return {
        init: init
    };
}();
```

And use `window` when calling it:

```
window.Doc.Show.init();
```

Comment: i tried your suggestion and still get the same error

Comment: if I do this:
var Doc = {};
it still gives me same error

Comment: Try `window.Doc = ...`

Comment: I'm not sure why you're getting an error for `Doc.show.init()`, since that's not in strict mode. But try the update I just made.

Comment: Unfortunately that does not work either
i now get "Show is not referenced or null" exception